# Invalidate Session only on Browser Close not on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, session

I want to invalidate the session when user closes the browser or tab but not when the user refreshes the page

The `beforeunload` event triggers on `hyperlink click` , `form Submission` , `Refresh` and on `Browser Close` .

I have detected form Submission and Hyperlink click , but not able to differentiate between `Refresh` and `Close`

**Code Used :**

```
var isLinkOrForm=false;
$("a").click(function(){
    isLinkOrForm=true; 
});
 $("form").submit(function (e){
    isLinkOrForm=true;
 });
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){
        console.log("Bind Event Invoked : "+isLinkOrForm);
        if(!isLinkOrForm){
            console.log("Inside the Invalidate Session condition :+isLinkOrForm);
            window.setTimeout(invalidateSessionOnBrowserClose(),500);
        }
         return null;
});
```

But with this code Session getting invalidated on both Refresh as well as on Browser Close . How to avoid this event on `Page Refresh`

**Note : ** Tried Cookie based solution described in other post on SO but that is not working